# Access part of module from pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have an issue accessing part of imported module from the pytest.

Here is branch with code referenced below: https://github.com/asvc/snapshotr/tree/develop

In particular, when running this test, it works as expected for `test_correct_installation()` but `test_script_name_checking()` fails with AttributeError.

```
import main as ss
import os

class TestInit:
    def test_correct_installation(self):
        assert os.path.exists(ss.snapr_path)
        assert os.path.isfile(ss.snapr_path + "/main/markup.py")
        assert os.path.isfile(ss.snapr_path + "/main/scandir.py")

    def test_script_name_checking(self):
        assert ss.ssPanel.check_script('blah') is None # Here it fails
```

[Link to the `main` which is being tested](https://github.com/artaman/snapshotr/blob/f5b3fe606dc2b70f9f4fb3a376a06a6cd94233b3/main/__init__.py)

What I'm trying to do is to "extract" isolated piece of code, run it with known data and compare result to some reference. Seems like extraction part doesn't work quite well, best practises for such cases would be greatly appreciated.

Traceback:
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ssPanel'`

I have tried a small hack in the `test_init.py`:

```
class dummy():
    pass

nuke = dummy()
nuke.GUI = True
```

But it (obviously) doesn't work as `nuke.GUI` is being redefined in `__init__.py` upon every launch.

Comment: Please add the traceback you are getting. Looking at the code, there's a `if nuke.GUI:` before the definition of `ssPanel`, my guess it is False so `ssPanel` never gets defined.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira Thanks, you are right, added details to the post. How one should deal with such cases, what's the best way to properly "isolate" certain part of code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite complex situation. When you import `main` in `test_init.py`, it will import `main/__init__.py` and execute all the code. This will cause `nuke` being imported and also, if `nuke.GUI` is False, there will not be `ssPanel`, as you can see.

The problem is that, you can't fake a dummy nuke in the test script. It won't work. Because before the test is running, the real nuke was already imported.

My suggestion would be seperate `ssPanel` into another python file. Then in `__init__.py` we can do:

```
if nuke.GUI:
    from sspanel import ssPanel
```

And in test scripts, we can also easily import it using:

```
from main.sspanel import ssPanel
```

Comment: Yes, probably worth to massively refactor `__init__.py`

Comment: Agreed. Better later than never.